# Documenting Javascript code in VSCode for Intellisense

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I'm trying to get proper Intellisense suggestions for my javascript code in Visual Studio Code. In particular, I have the following AngluarJS service:

```
/// <reference path="definitelytyped/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
var module = angular.module( 'testApp', [] );
module.factory( 'backend', function ( $http ) {
    return {
        "getComments": function HoverHereToSeeType( post ) {
            /// <summary>Retrieves comments from the backend</summary>
            /// <param name="post" type="string">Post to retrieve comments for</param>
            return $http.get( "/rest/" + post );
        }
    };
} )
```

I thought I should be using [XML Documentation Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh524453.aspx), but they don't seem to work - when I hover over `HoverHereToSeeType` the parameter is shown as "any" (while the return value is properly inferred using angular.d.ts). So the first part of the question is: How do I annotate types in my functions?

The second part of the question comes up when actually trying to use the service:

```
module.controller( 'MyCtrl', function( backend ) {
    backend.getComments( "test" );
} );
```

I get that IntelliSense doesn't understand Angular's dependency injection, so I'll need to annotate `backend`'s type. But how do I reference that type?

In short: How do I get proper Intellisense for the `backend.getComments()` call in the second snippet, i.e. the information that the parameter has to be a string and the returned value will be an ng.IHttpPromise?

Comment: have you tried typing `//**` then hit enter?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware I can do multiline comments using `/**`, but the important part of the question is how do I structure my comments so Intellisense parses them?

Comment: did you end up solving this? I'm only getting autocompletion for stuff that i require(), but it won't work if i take an object that i require and for example expose it in module.exports, and then reference this variable in another file

Comment: No, did not end up solving it.

Comment: A year later, but ... did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: I stopped trying, I don't use any Angular these days.

Answer (score 4):

This provides hover hints in TypeScript. Not exactly what you want, but if they extend this to show them in other files, it would be great.

```
/**
 * Change the role of the employee.
 * @param {number} x The id of the employee.
 */
tester: (x: number) => number = (x: number) => x * x;
```

Comment: But I'm writing JavaScript, where commenting with that syntax is apparently not picked up by IntelliSense.

Comment: @Mr.Wonko, you're using VSCode, which is not the same as Visual Studio. I've just tried — IntelliSense does work with JSDoc comments and doesn't with Visual Studio's XML comments. (Note that I've tried with JavaScript.)

Comment: Yes, I am using VSCode, wasn't that clear from my question? So when you say you just tried, do you mean with VS or with VSCode? Because in VSCode [it doesn't work for me](http://imgur.com/YL5AWdk).

Comment: What. Why doesn't it work that way for me? But still, that's not exactly what I'm after - the deduced type (top line in the popup) still ignores the comment, which is especially important for the return type (and getting auto-completion when working with it).

Comment: I have no slightest idea why it doesn't work for you. Maybe you have an idea why Git's pull/push doesn't work for me? (Probably because it is a beta.)

Comment: @Mr.Wonko, Yes. It completely ignores types in JSDoc, which annoys me a lot. But it seems it tries to deduce types itself. At least it does it for me for return types: http://imgur.com/9EubxA6

Comment: I haven't used it for git, so can't help you with that... I noticed it deduces the return types, but with Angular's depedency injections I need to specify a function's parameters to get useful auto-completion on my services.

Comment: @Mr.Wonko, what line-endings do you use in [your example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000950/documenting-javascript-code-in-vscode-for-intellisense/30018407#comment48384397_30018407) above?

Comment: @sigod whatever is the default, CRLF apparently.

Comment: I confirm the example provided by @sidog (http://imgur.com/AAKXl0u) does not propose completion from jsdoc annotations. This is pure deduction of vsCode from the javascript code: 
If you remove the return statment, the completion engine of vsCode behaves as if the method returns void (confirmed by tooltip by the way)

Answer (score 0):

1. Type angular on the first line of any javascript file in your open folder.
2. Notice the word "angular" is underlined and a lightbulb appears.

[image: Adding reference to Angular]

3. You have the option of adding a reference to angular. Do this.

Notice a new folder has appeared with this reference in it. You will now have intellisense.

[image: Typings folder]

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for Intellisense for the Angular library - I already have that, as evidenced by the <reference> comment - I want it for the code *I* wrote.